# How can i solve the problem with the props?

Tags: next.js

How to do the *state* was from the **pros** only 1 time? because I can't fetch in the client component, this example is from 1 page in large application, I can't get all the data from server in one request globally, because first request from get site will be long.

```
const Page = async () => { 
  const data = await fetchData('...');
  return <ClientComponent data={data} />;
};



const ClientComponent = ({ data }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(); // when component remount, state will be from props, this is problem
  
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    setState(data);
  }, [data]);

  const updateData = () => {
    setState(prev => prev.map('...')) // change state
  }
  
  return <>{state.map(v => <SomeComponent />)}</>
}
```